# socket recv hangs in Windows XP

Tags: windows, sockets

I have established TCP/IP socket connection between an Android device and a Windows host computer via USB. The port used for the connection is 8000/8001. This mode of communication works very well in Windows 7 and other ecosystems whereas on Windows XP 32 bit the "recv" API hangs indefinitely.

I wrote a sample program where the server and client runs on the Windows XP host and that works fine but when USB is involved the problem occurs. I used a sniffer tool "USB analyser" tool to sniff the data coming from the device and I see the data coming to the device but somehow the recv API is not able to capture it.

The code which I have used is present in the link below:
http://www.tenouk.com/Winsock/Winsock2example9.html

Thanks,
Nerd

Edit: This problem occurs only on Windows XP 32 bit and not on 64 bit.

Edit2: I have found a hack for this, immediately after the connection is established the server will send a dummy data and the client will capture it. If this is done then the recv will not hang further. Any clue as to why this is required?

Comment: Which are you using: TCP sockets, or UDP sockets?

Comment: I am using TCP sockets. I also found out that adding some delay before recv works fine.

Comment: It shouldn't make the slightest difference, unless you're in non-blocking mode, in which case you should be using `select()` rather than a sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some delay(100 ms) before the recv would resolve this issue. But I dont know the exact reason as to why this might be occuring.